# A question on periodicity of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Show that if $f(z)$ is an entire function such that it takes real values on the lines $Im(z)=0$ and $Im(z)=a$ (for some $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0})$, then $f$ is periodic with period $2 i a$.

So here is my thought process: First of all by reflection principle $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$ so if our function $f$ is given in the strip $0 \leq Im(z) \leq a$, then its values on $-a \leq Im(z) \leq a$ follow by reflection principle. Then by imposing $f(z)=f(z+2 ia)$ we can intuitively see that this will define an entire function by looking at how the strips $na \leq Im(z) \leq 2na$ seamlessly stack on top of each other. Is this logical? And how would one prove this analytically?

Comment: where is this question from?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with the reflection principle, you can show that $f(x-ia) = \overline {f(x+ia)} = f(x+ia)$.

So if you define $g(z) = f(x+ia)-f(x-ia)$, $g$ is entire and is identically $0$ on the real axis.
Then by the identity theorem, $g = 0$ on all of $\Bbb C$, which means that $f$ is $2ia$-periodic.